# Using 'Between' operator after 'THEN' within 'CASE' statement within 'WHERE'

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do something like this

```
select *
from m
where CASE WHEN x=1 THEN trunc(m.ATT_DATE) between '18-01-01' AND '18-12-31'
WHEN x=2 THEN trunc(m.main_date) between '18-01-01' AND '18-12-31'
ELSE 1 END = 1;
```

x is a variable

I get this error
ORA-00905: mot-clé absent
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:
Erreur à la ligne 182, colonne 42

Comment: `THEN` must be followed by an expression (like the constant `1` you have after the `END` keyword). It cannot be followed by a condition. What should the condition be? Describe it in words. Should it be that "x = 1 and ATT_DATE between ...." or "x = 2 and ATT_DATE between...." or "x not in (1, 2)"? If that is the case (or if something similar), then write it that way. Why do you want/need a `CASE `construct anyway?

Answer (score 4):

I would write this as:

```
select m.*
from m
where (x = 1 and trunc(m.ATT_DATE) between date '2018-01-01' and date '2018-12-31') or
      (x = 2 and trunc(m.main_date) between date '2018-01-01' and date '2018-12-31') or
      (x not in (1, 2));
```

Notes:

- Usually, `case` expressions can be replaced by simple boolean logic in a `where` clause.
- One of the problems with your query is that Oracle doesn't recognize booleans, so a `then` clause cannot return a boolean expression.
- Date constants should be introduced with the `date` keywords.
- Date constants should use an ANSI/ISO standard format, such as YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put logic inside the case result like that, and if  you could then you'd have a boolean result mixed with a numerical result.

Depending on what you want to happen if `x` is neither 1 nor 2, you could either return nothing in that situation with one of these:

```
select *
from m
where (x=1 and trunc(m.att_date) between date '2018-01-01' and date '2018-12-31')
  or (x=2 and trunc(m.main_date) between date '2018-01-01' and date '2018-12-31');

select *
from m
where (x=1 and m.att_date >= date '2018-01-01' and m.att_date < date '2019-01-01')
  or (x=2 and m.main_date >= date '2018-01-01' and m.main_date < date '2019-01-01');

select *
from m
where case when x=1 then m.att_date when x=2 then m.main_date end >= date '2018-01-01'
  and case when x=1 then m.att_date when x=2 then m.main_date end < date '2019-01-01';
```

where the last two compare against a full date/time range instead of using `trunc()` which would prevent any indexes on those columns being used; or if you want to include all rows when `x` is not 1 or 2:

```
select *
from m
where (x=1 and trunc(m.att_date) between date '2018-01-01' and date '2018-12-31')
  or (x=2 and trunc(m.main_date) between date '2018-01-01' and date '2018-12-31')
  or x not in (1,2);

select *
from m
where (x=1 and m.att_date >= date '2018-01-01' and m.att_date < date '2019-01-01')
  or (x=2 and m.main_date >= date '2018-01-01' and m.main_date < date '2019-01-01')
  or x not in (1,2);

select *
from m
where case when x=1 then m.att_date when x=2 then m.main_date
    else date '2018-01-01' end >= date '2018-01-01'
  and case when x=1 then m.att_date when x=2 then m.main_date
    else date '2018-01-01' end < date '2019-01-01';
```

The first two add explicit checks for `x` (and the first is what @Gordon is doing...); the third uses the `case .. else ..` to supply a default value that is in the range, which is probably going to end up doing more work than really necessary.

Personally I'd use the middle one in each case.

Comment: Thank you all, it's working now
I have used: (x = 1 and trunc(m.ATT_DATE) between date '2018-01-01' and date '2018-12-31') or
      (x = 2 and trunc(m.main_date) between date '2018-01-01' and date '2018-12-31')
instead of
CASE WHEN x=1 THEN trunc(m.ATT_DATE) between '18-01-01' AND '18-12-31'
WHEN x=2 THEN trunc(m.main_date) between '18-01-01' AND '18-12-31'
ELSE 1 END = 1